# Android sendevent command not work until finger touch once

Tags: shell, adb

I want to use `sendevent` command to simulate touch event, I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1173378/using-adb-to-sendevent-touches-to-the-phone-but-cant-release) link, and it works.

Use `getevent` to record, then use `sendevent` to repeat them, code like below, it can tap position 540 1802.

> ```
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 0
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 540
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 1802
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 -1
>   sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
> ```

There's only one problem, if device reboot, `sendevent` won't work, I have to use my finger to touch screen once, then it will work again.

How to let it work without any manually touch?

Comment: It may be a certain flag like "user active" .. You may need to simulate a key input, or something to trigger the "user active" flag.

Comment: I think your comment may be a reason, but do you know more details? I have no idea how to active device. No password is set on this device, it will go to launcher directly, I also tried to set password and enter password via `input` command, `sendevent` still won't work after unlocked.

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause it other than some sort of User Active check... I can only think of a few ways programmatically that would work. .. Maybe the input hasn't been initiated yet and it requires a start of input prior to sending events to it... for adb I use `input tap 540 1802`... So full command would be `adb shell input tap 540 1802` ... Maybe try this first before sending more events... Not sure.

Comment: Even `input tap` first, `sendevent` still not work. OK, thanks anyway.

Comment: I can't find anything relating to this issue, it may be device specific.

Comment: Just skittering past while trying to to figure out a different problem - I realize this is very old, but just thought of this, and just in case - it's *possible* the touchscreen requires/does some sort of dance on the first tap event. If this is the case then replaying the firehose that happens on first touch after reboot may jog things into cooperating. (Ideally you'd then whittle down the minimum sequence necessary to make things work over a series of patience-trying reboots :D)

Comment: (It is also sadly quite possible a physical-tap flag was involved here somewhere, to try and make fraud etc trickier. Possibly)